# Webscraping code is not collecting all product URLs

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to collect all product URLs on this website: https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799

**What I've done**
I implemented the code below, which first finds the total number of products (~18k) and the number of products per page (72). Using these numbers, I calculate the number of pages total. Then, I iterate through each page to collect all product urls per page.

**Expected Result**
I expect to end up with a product_urls list of length equal to the total number of products (~18k). However, this is the output for the first 5 pages (it's not collecting all product urls):

```
Page 0 done. URLs collected: 72
Page 1 done. URLs collected: 72
Page 2 done. URLs collected: 0
Page 3 done. URLs collected: 0
Page 4 done. URLs collected: 0
Total number of product urls: 144
```

**Code**

```
# Upload google drive files
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Import libraries
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO 

# Beautiful soup function
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

def make_soup(url):
    request= urllib.request.Request(url, None,headers) 
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

# Get total number of pages 

site = 'https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799'
soup = make_soup(site)
element = soup.find('p', class_='label_Ph1fi')
element = element.text

numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*', element)

if len(numbers) >= 2:
    offset = int(numbers[0].replace(',', ''))
    num_images = int(numbers[1].replace(',', ''))
    num_pages = int(num_images / offset)
    print(f"Images Per Page: {offset}")
    print(f"Total Images: {num_images}")
    print(f"Total Pages:{num_pages}")
else:
    print("Numbers not found")

# Get all product urls 

product_urls = []
for i in range(5): # testing with 5 instead of num_pages 
    site = 'https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799&page='
    site = site + str(i)
    soup = make_soup(site)
    items = soup.find_all('a',class_='productLink_E9Lfb',href=True)
    url_cnt = 0
    for link in items:
        href = link.get('href')
        if href:
            product_urls.append(href)
            url_cnt += 1
    
    print(f'Page {i} done. URLs collected: {url_cnt}')

print(f'Total number of product urls: {len(product_urls)}')
```

Comment: All the products after page 1 are added dynamically with JavaScript, they're not in the HTML. You'll need to use Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: you don't need to load each page in a loop. Just go to the last page number, it will have everything (when you use Selenium).